# How do I concatenate an array value to string in swift 3?

Tags: swift

How do I join an array value to a string? I tried the following but got bad instruction error, appreciate any help. Sorry if my code looks bad as I'm still a student new to swift, hehe.

```
if let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: unwrappedData, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:Any] {
    if let test = jsonData["firstname"] as? String {
        let postString = "type=" + jsonData["firstname"] + "&type=insert"
    }
}
```

Comment: If you already have `jsonData["test"]` conditionally bound to `test`, why do you use it, rather than `test`?

Comment: Hi, is just a test post to the server with my php script. It returns json and I'm trying to access its array.

Comment: You didn't answer my question

Comment: Sorry I don't get what you mean? Because actually jsonData["test"] is a firstname. Sorry as the variable name is abit confusing. I will change to better illustrate

Comment: You took the expression `jsonData["firstname"] as? String`, and you conditionally bound its result to the variable `test`. But within that `if let` block, you use `jsonData["firstname"]`, and not the `test` variable that you just bound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

`let postString = "type=" + jsonData["firstname"] + "&type=insert"`

to

`let postString = "type=" + test + "&type=insert"`

since you are assigning the non-nil value to `test`

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I tried and now I've got the error EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION which is the same error I've got previously.

Comment: Also got this in the log fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Is your object being correctly serialized by `JSONSerialization `?

Comment: It could be because `unwrappedData` is nil, and you are telling `JSONSerialization` to serialize an object, which is nil. Check the definition of your `unwrappedData`, maybe it is nil. Try adding the line `if let data = unwrappedData { print("unwrappedData not nil") }` above your code. Does it print the statement inside the if clause?

Comment: I tried to print(jsonData) and this is what php returns me: ["type": Bearer, "firstname": john, "lastname":"depp"]. Is it something I did wrong in PHP?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry it works now! Thank you soo much for your help!

Comment: You are very welcome. If you can, please add your solution to the comments to let others know what solved your problem.